# Combine two collections with same document structure in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, acknowledgements and acknowlegements_temp. The second is a result of an $out at the end of an aggregation query transforming data from an old structure. I was hoping I could use $out to add to acknowledgements directly, but apparently it overwrites.

How can I merge these two collections? I don't need to merge individual documents, just add one set of documents to another.

My migration query:

```
db.actions.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { actionType: 'acknowledge' }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$applicationIds'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            userId: 1,
            nagId: "$applicationIds.applicationId",
            date: "$applicationIds.addedOn",
            actioned: "$applicationIds.actioned"
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "acknowledgements"
    }
])
```

Comment: have you tried a `for(...) { insert() }`, either in the console or using a tool? Shouldn't be more than a two-liner I guess. If the collection is large, I'd make sure you can resume the operation should it fail in between

Comment: Perhaps it could help if you paste the code you have tried.